# Can't Install DNN 6.2.9 - 302 Redirect Loop Timeout

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, dotnetnuke, http-status-code-302, dotnetnuke-6

I'm trying to install DNN version 6.2.9 (I have to use this version for the client I'm working with), but I'm not being able to get the installer to work. I've followed all the steps at this link:

http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/how-to-install-dotnetnuke

When I get to the step where I'm supposed to go to the installation wizard on localhost, step 10, the browser-based installer isn't loading. When I investigated the network traffic, it appears the installer is trapped in a 302 redirect loop and the request to the server is timing out. Below are the two urls it keeps alternating between. Any thoughts on what could be causing this? I suspect some kind of permissions or maybe db access problem, but I haven't been able to find a solution yet.

```
Local host prefix: localhost/dotnetnuke
```

Two .aspx files it keeps alternating between:

```
login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fdotnetnuke%2fInstall%2fInstallWizard.aspx

Install/InstallWizard.aspx
```

Answer (score 0):

Are any of the database tables, stored procedures, etc. created?  This is often an issue reading the PortalAlias information - so I would check that you have DB access, write permissions (the installer should do that for you anyway). If everything is created, check the portal alias table.

I would also check relevant file permissions mentioned in the guide.